# moving 2d object unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have 1 year experience of coding in C++ , but just yesterday i've started learning Unity.I saw it needs C# so this won't be too different.Right now , I am trying to move a 2d object , but i really want to understand how it works and not just copy some lines of code.So , this is how they do it :

```
//
float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
//which i assume gets the x coordonate of my object;
myRigidBody.velocity = new vector2(horizontal , myRigidBody.velocity.y);
//
```

And i don't think i get the idea of this code.I read that velocity takes 2 values (x,y) but i am not quite sure what it is doing with them.And getAxis takes a value from [-1,1] which i also don't understand.If you could help me i'd be grateful.

Comment: Npthing to do with your question (which seems to be about an API, not about any language issues) but C# and C++ are very different. C# is much more like Java than C++.

Comment: oh , thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

`Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");` returns the current value for the axis named `Horizontal` as defined in Unity's Input manager.

Also, `new vector2(horizontal, myRigidBody.veloicty.y);`  is probably a typo, because the type of [`Rigidbody.velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html) is `Vector3`. And `Vector2` is an object that [has an implicit conversion to `Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-operator_Vector2.html).

Anyway, `myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal , myRigidBody.velocity.y);` creates an instance of a `Vector2` type where the x component is `horizontal`, and the y component is the current y component of the rigidbody's velocity, and then it assigns that `Vector2` to the rigidbody's velocity.

Answer (score 0):

GetAxis("Horizontal") returns the values from left (-1,0,0) and right (1,0,0) when you press the arrows keys. Anyway, you'll get the values interpolated and not a sudden change. Try the code below and see how it looks on the inspector

```
  public float horizontal;
  private void Update()
    {
       horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    }
```

As for the velocity, you "force change" the velocity of the rigidbody in any direction you want x,y (horizontal,vertical axis). You can also multiply your axis values with a speed variable.

Comment: Ohh so when it reaches 1 or -1 , it means it gets the maximum speed?

Comment: I wouldn't say maximum "speed" but more like a maximum "throttle" when you floor the pedal of a car. You can have 25km/h, it's not maximum speed but accelerate as fast as you car can.